# Two tangent circles and parallel lines

Tags: geometry

I have problems in solving the following problem:

Consider two circles which have only one point $A$ in common, i.e. which are tangent to each other. Now consider two lines through A, such that the lines meet the circles at further points $B,C,D,E$. I want to prove that the lines $DE$ and $BC$ are parallel lines ($D,E$ being points on one circle and $B,C$ on the other).

I tried to use theorems like the inscribed angle theorem, but I was not succesfull so far. Does someone know how to solve this problem?

If it is possible, I only want to use geometric arguments, and not analytical arguments. Does this result have any name?

Best wishes

Comment: This theorem is true if the circles are of the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $M,N$ two points on the common tangent at opposite sides with respect to $A$, than $\angle DAM = \angle DEA$ because they subtend the same arc $DA$ ( $\angle DAM$ is a ''limit'' angle, being  the side $AM$ tangent, but, if you don't like the concept of ''limit'' angle, you can proof the same claim as a consequence of the [tangent-secant theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Tangent_Secant_Theorem).).

In the same manner $\angle BAN=\angle BCA$.

Now note that $\angle DAM$ and $\angle BAN$ are opposed, and .....

I don't know if this result has a special name.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Problem Figure.]

Let the common tangent $L$ be drawn.
Then, by the Alternate Segment Theorem:
$$\angle DEA =\angle (DA,L)$$
And similarly:
$$\angle CBA=\angle (CA,L)$$
But the latter are equal as they are vertically opposite.
Therefore it follows that the angles
Intercepted by $BE$ are equal and thus, the lines are parallel.

---

This is a special **limiting** case of the *Reim's Theorem*, which states that lines through the points of intersection of two circles cut the circle in points that form two parallel segments.

This is not a well-known theorem by the way.